# How to add font assets to a Unity based Android app on runtime?

Tags: unity, android

I am working on an `android` app that contains a `Unity` scene. The unity scene has some `TextMeshPro` text fields where user can enter information. Users also have the option to select fonts for these text fields.

I want to support a lot of fonts. Right now I add all the font assets in Unity. But these font assets add up to increase the app size a lot.

I am trying to find out if there is a way to download these fonts at runtime as per the user's choice so that the initial app size is small? Is this possible?

I would appreciate any links, tutorials, or help. I've not been able to find any information regarding this so far. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using AssetBundles or Addressables for this purpose?

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't, didn't know about these. Looks like what I need. I'd look into these. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you find they work for you, please share an Answer below explaining how you used them, so it can benefit other users struggling with similar problems.

Comment: @DMGregory sure, will do.

Comment: I'm honestly just curious as to why you need that many fonts that file size becomes an issue. Is it for language support?